# Understanding Module Require Syntax of Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have recently come across this line of code.

```
const { Bar, Data: { Selectors } } = require('some-module');
```

Can someone please tell me what does `Data: { Selectors }` do in this piece of code? I understand that it is importing  some module in my codebase, just confused about the `{Selectors}` part.

Also, if I want to write it using `import` syntax what would be the equivalent code for the same?

e.g : `import Bar from "some-module"`

Comment: It's just nested destructuring.

Comment: What the equivalent `import` syntax would depend a lot on what `export` syntax the ES6 version of `some-module` uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really have to do with modules (syntax is the same for import or require: `import {Bar} from "some-module"` ), it's just a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) creating two variables, `Bar` and `Selector`.

Here's another example along with many other ES6 features http://es6-features.org/#ObjectMatchingDeepMatching

```js
    const obj = {Bar: 1, Data: { Selectors: [1,2]}};
    const { Bar, Data: { Selectors } } = obj;
    // This is another ES6 feature, same as saying
    // console.log({Bar: Bar})
    console.log({Bar});
    console.log({Selectors});
```

The above is the same as saying

```
 const Bar = obj.Bar;
 const Selectors = obj.Data.Selectors
```